# How to install an old version of a Visual Studio preview version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2022 Preview 2.1 but it [constantly hangs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-hangs-on-a-test-project/1477250?entry=myfeedback) when editing razor files.

I would use Visual Studio 2019 but it is not so simple as I have made extensive use of the `global using` directive.

I was wondering if there was a way to downgrade to the earlier preview of Visual Studio 2022 Preview 1.1 which worked very well.

I found a site where one could find all [previous releases of VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history) however that is not of much use to me.

Comment: any chance you have the url for preview 3.1 too?

Comment: @SaschaW, no, I would ask on the VS developer community. That is where I got the url to 1.1.

Comment: @SaschaW, what is wrong with 4.0? Should I not install it?

Comment: I upgrade to preview 4.1 and got stackoverflow exception, can't fix, need find preview 3.1 installer if someone have.

Comment: Have you found the installer for 3.1? 4.1 is broken for me as well.